# MassTransit default value of WaitTimeSeconds

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, amazon-sqs, masstransit

We have MassTransit in our project. What is the value of WaitTimeSeconds by default?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version, the [latest release](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/Transports/MassTransit.AmazonSqsTransport/Topology/Settings/QueueReceiveSettings.cs#L19) defaults to 3 seconds. Earlier versions defaulted to 1 second.